# php and htaccess, url rewriting by mysql table id and other column

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Hi my mysql table is in this way

```
[ID] [TITLE] [SEOLINK]
[1] [Test] [test]
[2] [Test 2] [test-2]
```

My php url is in this way
example.com/index.php?id=2

how to htaccess rewrite, so link can be
example.com/page/test-2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule will accept URLs in the format `/page/this-is-my-page-title-123` where 123 is the id of the page.

It will also be QueryString Aware (meaning you can add ?param=value at the end, and that will be processed)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/[\w\-]+(\d)+ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, mysql condition had to be changed.

```
$query = "select * from TABLE where ID = '".$_GET['id']."'";
mysql_query($query);

to 

$query = "select * from TABLE where SEOLINK = '".$_GET['param']."'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Now, you can use `RedirectRule` in `.htaccess`. like:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?param=$1 [NC]
```